# Can I open a question about Social Media?

Tags: support

Just wondering: Can I open a question about Social Media Management and Strategy? If answer is no, then, is there other StackExchange site for this?

Answer (score 1):

If the question is related to social media management and strategy *for your own website*, then it would be fine here.

Social media management and strategy for a startup company could be asked at http://answers.onstartups.com/

Other questions about Facebook, Twitter, and other social media might be appropriate ot https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It is about Youtube and Vimeo. The title for the question would be: "How important is to have a Vimeo account if I already use YouTube?". Does this question fit here?

Comment: No, it doesn't sound like it is about your own website.

Comment: It is about a business site of my own: www.simplementeweb.com  The question is about how to use YouTube and Vimeo for Social Media purposes for my site.

Comment: If you ask the question, make it clear that it is about the promotion of your website.  There could be other problems with that question though. "Is it important" isn't good because that is asking for opinions.