# Are social media marketing questions on-topic?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

When I tried to tag this question [What is the difference between two URL in Facebook Ad Manager?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/125520/52079), I found that there is no tag about [facebook-ads-manager](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-ads-manager) or similar tags. This raised a suspicion that this type of question is off-topic here, because I suppose Facebook advertising is as important as Google advertising for marketers. So if it's on-topic, someone should have asked it before I guess.

According to [What topics can I ask about here?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), apparently internet marketing is on-topic here. I wonder this includes social media marketing as well?

The answer for the question [Can I open a question about Social Media?](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1077/52079) says "If the question is related to social media management and strategy for your own website, then it would be fine here." I understand that it's a yes. I'm not sure that it's correct or not.

Comment: I added the requested tag to your question.

Comment: so is it on-topic?

Comment: @Ooker Yes, it's on-topic. Like all questions though, it really depends on what's specifically being asked: if it's a question about how to use Facebook in some way that's not clear how it relates to your site, then it might be a better fit for Web Applications. If it's solely related to coding, then it might be better suited for Stack Overflow...So if it's in relationship to your website and not better suited to another Stack site, it's most likely on-topic here.

Comment: @dan the problem is that Facebook Ads Manager is not just about managing ads linking to your site, but also native ads on Facebook as well. For those posts, I would say they are more about using Facebook solely, but one can reasonably argue that it's also about the site

Comment: @Ooker I see. In the case that they're just about ads on Facebook, they'd likely be migrated to [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/) since they seem to accept questions related to [that](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/search?q=facebook+ads+is%3Aq). For sake of closing this question out, you can paraphrase the above comments into an answer, or Stephen or I can do so if you like.

Comment: @dan and this is where I ask: internet marketing is on-topic. Since running native ads on Facebook is a part of social marketing, which is a part of internet marketing, so it should be on-topic too. If the community want to exclude running native ads on social media, the on-topic page should be updated to reflect that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Questions about Facebook Ad Manager and other social media marketing would usually be on-topic here.   As long as you are using Facebook Ads to drive traffic to your website, you could ask about:

- Ad buying strategies
- How to use the user interface
- Problems with your account there
- Changes to the service

This is similar to how we treat other web services related to running your website:

- Analytics
- Google AdWords and AdSense
- Webmaster tools from Google, Bing, and Yandex

There could be questions about Facebook Ad Manager that don't involve your website at all.  Those questions would not be on-topic.  For example, if you were running ads on Facebook meant to promote things other than your website:

- Your app
- Your Facebook page or group
- Your brand
- A politician
- An ideology

---

As an aside, please don't take the presence or absence of a tag as evidence that something is on-topic or off-topic.   Every on-topic tag has to be created by somebody with enough reputation at some point.  That somebody could well be you.   We have tags where nearly every question tagged would be off-topic.  An example is [looking-for-a-script](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/looking-for-a-script) which was used heavily in the first couple years of the site, but which asks for product recommendations which we now routinely close down as off-topic.

Comment: do you think the on-topic page should be updated to reflect this? Or at least a link to here?

Comment: My answer is based on the on-topic page.   If it is about your website, it is on-topic.  Although maybe we should change "internet marketing" to "internet and social media marketing for your website"